# moving an object in a fixed circular path in android

Tags: android, animation, math, android-animation

I want to move an object in a fixed circular path like the planets around the sun.

Here is the link as per my research:
[how to make an object move in circular path?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24242243/how-to-make-an-object-move-in-circular-path?answertab=active#tab-top)
However, it is not working.

Here is the updated code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ourView v;

Bitmap tball;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    v = new ourView(this);

    setContentView(v);
    tball = (BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.blueball));

}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    v.pause();
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    v.resume();
}

public class ourView extends SurfaceView implements Runnable {
    Thread t;
    SurfaceHolder holder;
    Boolean isitok = false;

    public ourView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        holder = getHolder();

    }

    // float aX, aY;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while (isitok == true) {
            // perform drawing
            if (!holder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                continue;
            }
            Canvas canvas = holder.lockCanvas();
            canvas.drawARGB(255, 150, 150, 10);

            // System.out.println("Canvas matrix  -" + canvas.getm));
            Paint p = new Paint();

            // canvas.drawBitmap(tball, (x - tball.getWidth()) / 2,
            // (y - tball.getHeight()) / 2, p);
            p.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
            p.setColor(Color.WHITE);
            p.setColor(Color.parseColor("#0101DF"));

            canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth() / 2,
                    canvas.getHeight() / 2, 110, p);
            canvas.drawCircle(canvas.getWidth() / 2,
                    canvas.getHeight() / 2, 210, p);

            float x = (canvas.getWidth() / 2) - (tball.getWidth() / 2);
            float y = (canvas.getHeight() / 2) - 210 + (210 - 110) / 2
                    - (tball.getHeight() / 2);
            float MX = canvas.getWidth() / 2;
            float MY = canvas.getHeight() / 2;

            for (double i = 0; i < 12 ; i++) {
                float R = 160;
                x = (float) (MX + (R * Math.cos(i)));
                y = (float) (MY + (R * Math.sin(i)));
                //y = (float) (MY - (R * Math.sin( i )));
                canvas.drawBitmap(tball, x, y, p);

                i++;
            }

            // float movingpts[];

            holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
        }
    }

    public void pause() {
        isitok = false;
        while (true) {
            try {
                t.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            break;
        }
        t = null;
    }

    public void resume() {
        isitok = true;
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();

    }

}

}"
```

`

Comment: Please read the [How to Ask section](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). What's not working? What's the error? Please provide more information, and try to ask a _specific_ question, or you're unlikely to get help.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/). This is an animation library available on every android version back to 1.0. I don't know if its possible to achieve an fixed circular path animation but the library seems pretty powerful.

Here is the sample code for a path animation: [link-to-sample](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids/tree/master/sample/src/com/jakewharton/nineoldandroids/sample/pathanimation)